# How come font is different on iPhone and normal on desktops?

Tags: html, css

I have created an HTML/CSS page, but the font appears differently on the iPhone Safari browser compared to desktop browsers. I want the font to be Comic Sans but comes out in a different font.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "myFont";
  src: url("myFont.woff2");
}

html {
  font-family: "myFont", Comic Sans MS;
}

code {
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
}

table,
tr,
td {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #f7f2db;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  line-height: inherit;
  font-family: Comic Sans MS;
}
```

```html
<table id="u_content_text_3" style="font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;" role="presentation" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="v-container-padding-padding" style="overflow-wrap:break-word;word-break:break-word;padding:0px 10px 10px 20px;font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;" align="left">

        <div class="v-color v-text-align" style="color: #000000; line-height: 170%; text-align: left; word-wrap: break-word;">
          <p style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 170%; text-align: center;"><span style="font-size: 20px; line-height: 34px; font-family:'Comic Sans MS';">Demonstrate your affection to the special person in your life express your love, whether it be on a special occasion or just make the effort to show that you care.<br />Let your actions speak louder than words and show how much you truly love them.</span></p>
        </div>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried almost everything please help I'm lost on how to correct it on iPhone browsers. It works fine on desktop but not on iPhone/Android

Comment: The first step I would take would be moving the inline styles to your stylesheet using classes etc.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it’s not working on iPhone is that the Comic Sans font is not installed. Comic Sans is owned by Microsoft, I’m guessing it’s installed by default on Windows, and if you install Office on a Mac it gets installed as part of that. But the font is not installed on iPhone.

If you want consistency of fonts across devices, you need to use either a hosted webfont, or convert a desktop font to a webfont and host it yourself.

The simplest solution would be switch to a hosted webfont which looks similar. Try [Comic Neue](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Comic+Neue) by Google. The great thing about Google’s fonts is that they are all open source and free.

If you have access to a font file (typically `.ttf` or `.otf`) you can [convert that font to a webfont](https://transfonter.org/) and then host it yourself. However, note that taking a desktop font and republishing it on the web may contravene the licence agreement for the font.